# What makes for a good jungle god?

Tags: smite

Since I tend to spend most of my time playing Smite in Assault, I have very little experience with jungling. What qualities are valuable for a god to take into the jungle?

Answer (score 2):

The Jungler's primary function in Smite is to support laning Gods by helping them get kills, giving them time to push their lane and hopefully take a tower or phoenix. When a Jungler attacks a lane from the jungle, taking the enemy God by surprise, this is known as a Gank.

In order to do this, the Jungler often requires a form of Crowd Control and large damage output. This allows both the Jungler and the friendly laning God to do as much damage as possible before the enemy God reaches a safe space, like within the boundary of their Tower or Phoenix.

Their are many Jungle Gods, but most fall into one of two categories - early game carries or late game carries (in layman's terms, Gods who are better earlier in the match but aren't very useful later on, and Gods who are better later in the match but can't do much earlier on). An example of an early game carry is Thanatos, and an example of a late game carry is Kali.

As the Jungler is required to move from lane to lane, taking camps as often as possible and ganking enemy Gods, the most important aspects of a Jungle God are;

1. The ability to secure kills
2. Mobility
3. Crowd control capabilities

Answer (score 0):

First off mobility is very important since you constantly move between lanes.

Having a god that has some good minion clear is also essential since you don't want to take too clearing your jungle camps and buffs.

As long as you have those two in there you should be fine.