# How do you jungle in Smite?

Tags: smite

I'm not very familiar with jungling in Smite. Assuming that you've picked an [appropriate jungler](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/221529/68492), what does the jungler do during the course of the game?

Some information I'm looking for is:

- Starting strategy
- Things to keep an eye out for
- Mid-game role
- Late-game role
- Tactics to handle team fights
- Anything else worth mentioning

Comment: Just a question, are you taking out there lanes so they cant get it or are you taking out your buffs so your team doesnt need to spend time to get the buff by kill the monster who stands with the buff?

Answer (score 6):

**What do do as jungler?**

The most common approach is to first clear the midcamp on the side of the solo lane together with the mid laner and the solo laner. After that the mid laner goes to his lane and you do two jungle buffs with the support. Depending on your god you either take damage or speed. Then you take the mana buff with the solo laner.

- Throughout the game make sure you get to your jungle camps in time, gank mid and solo lane as much as you can to get a experience advantage.

  *Making a jungle camp in time means that you are there when it spawns. Later in the game this isn't as much of a priority anymore since you spend your time ganking lanes.*
- Its also your task to call for a Gold Fury or Fire Giant attempt.

Another popular approach is invading. The mid laner takes the midcamp on his own while you and the support try to take the opponents mana buff. They are likely to be here with their jungle, if you can try to steal their mana camp. You don't even have to obtain it since they can't pick it up anymore. This sets back the enemies solo laner a lot since he constantly needs to get back to base for mana.

I am sure there are a lot of other approaches but these are the most common ones.

**Item build**

Your build is important too, some people start with a 800 gold item and a damage potion which is 400 gold. This is a risk because if you die you lose 400 gold and get behind on the enemies jungler!

Keep in mind that clearing jungle camps is a high early game priority. So you may want to buy some items that help with that, for example 'Hand of the Gods' this can later also be used to kill the Gold Fury or Fire Giant when they are below 25% (Only if its build out).

**Team fights**

If someone dies in a team fight and the enemy can push because there is nobody who can defend it you have to be a stand in for this lane and defend it until someone gets back to lane.

Comment: So, I've been thinking about this answer. This probably makes sense if you're already familiar with jungling, but it seems just vague enough to not really help describe it. For example, the solo lane isn't always on the right, and there's no real concept of what "on time" is when it comes to clearing jungle camps. I think it'd help to have a couple examples in order to establish a base guideline to jungling, perhaps even include jungle camp timers, and then point out other details that junglers should watch out for.

Comment: @Ellesedil Did some edit, this covers all the knowledge I have on this subject :)

Answer (score 1):

As a jungler you're main job is to mainly rotate with your mid, and solo. A tip I can give you as a former main jungle, never clear minions without your mid or solo, its a bad move cause your mid just lost XP and gold, you need to stall the wave by letting the minions fight, if your mid is still not there before the last big creep is dead than go ahead and kill the rest, its his fault for not being there. Or if he is dead, that's the only acception. Also if you play thanatos in the jungle you do not need bumbas mask, get death toll and tier 1 boots. Also, get wrath relic for early game gold fury.